# Filter by context/domain in Odoo 10

Tags: xml, filtering, odoo, formview, xmlformview

I have created a model `Student` with variables `id`, `name`, `course`. I need to display only students from `courses` *x and y* **OR** with `names` *a and b* in my xml form view. What I would do is add a context to the action associated to my form view like this:

```
<record id="action_view_student" model="ir.actions.act_window.view">
        <field name="view_mode">tree</field>
        <field name="view_id" ref="view_student" />
        <field name="act_window_id" ref="action_view_student" />
        <field name="domain">[('name', 'in', ['a','b']) **OR** ('course', 'in', ['x','y'])]</field>
     </record>
```

I am not sure how to set the **OR** in the domain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's well documented [for example in the V11 Documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/reference/orm.html#domains)

The logical operators are prefixes and pay attention to the arity.

Your example would be:

`['|', ('name', 'in', ['a','b']), ('course', 'in', ['x','y'])]`

which reads name equals 'a' or 'b' OR course equals 'x' or 'y'

Where

`['|', ('name', 'in', ['a','b']), ('course', 'in', ['x','y']), ('active', '=', True)]`

reads (name equals 'a' or 'b' OR course equals 'x' or 'y') AND is active